# PHP not populating $_POST variable if doing a POST using multipart/form-data

Tags: php, post, header, request

so I make this manual POST request:

Headers

```
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: myhost.com
Content-Length: 11
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=xYzZY
Te: deflate,gzip;q=0.3
Connection: close
```

Request Body:

```
from=lalala
```

But then inspecting the $_POST variable from the site reveals that the variable is empty...

If I make it application/x-www-form-urlencoded, though

```
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: myhost.com
Content-Length: 11
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; boundary=xYzZY
Te: deflate,gzip;q=0.3
Connection: close
```

The $_POST variable would get populated correctly...

Why didn't the $_POST variable get populated when using multipart/form-data? How do I go about making it work using multipart/form-data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because [`multipart/form-data`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.2) is in a totally different format. You supplied the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format in both cases.